# Cpanel like platform

Tags: server, webserver

I'm looking for a automated point-and-click hosting platform like [Cpanel](http://www.cpanel.net/). Is any free and open source platform and which of them do you thing is the best? I prefer to be free of charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a long list of free hosting panels available at the [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/HostingControlPanels), but I can't vouch for any of them myself as I haven't tried any.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a cpanel lookalike module ?

I think you can try [virtualmin](http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html)

Answer (score 2):

**EHCP** or **Easy Hosting Control Panel** is a great alternative for cPanel. I have used and implemented it.

Google for "ehcp on ubuntu". It is very easy to install.

Run the following commands in terminal to install ehcp:

```
wget -O ehcp.tgz www.ehcp.net/ehcp_latest.tgz
tar -zxvf ehcp.tgz
cd ehcp
./install.sh
```

Comment: does it allow for DNS configuration, such as enabling DKIM and SPF?

Answer (score 2):

Vesta CP is definitely the best choice, it is easy to install and also has great performance. I love that it uses Nginx and also SpamAssassin and fail2ban. That makes for a more secure installation, and the control panel is clean and easy to manage. I wrote a small tutorial on how to install with these features [here](http://www.ubuntuboss.com/install-vesta-control-panel-ubuntu-14-04-3/). Note: this is for Ubuntu 14.04 but should work for most Linux distributions.